# Task scheduling with spark

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am running fairly large task on my 4 node cluster. I am reading around 4 GB of filtered data from a single table and running Naïve Baye’s training and prediction. I have HBase  region server running on a single machine which is separate from the spark cluster running in fair scheduling mode, although HDFS is running on all machines.

While executing, I am experiencing strange task distribution in terms of the number of active tasks on the cluster. I observed that only one active task or at most two tasks are running on one/two machines at any point of time while the other are sitting idle. My expectation was that the data in the RDD will be divided and processed on all the nodes for operations like count and distinct etcetera. Why are all nodes not being used for large tasks of a single job? Does having HBase on a separate machine has anything to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to check:

1. Presumably you are reading in your data using `hadoopFile()` or `hadoopRDD()`: consider setting the [optional] `minPartitions` parameter to make sure the number of partitions is equal to the number of nodes you want to use.
2. As you create other `RDD`s in your application, check the number of partitions of those `RDD`s and how evenly the data is distributed across them. (Sometimes an operation can create an `RDD` with the same number of partitions but can make the data within it badly unbalanced.) You can check this by calling the `glom()` method, printing the number of elements of the resulting `RDD` (the number of partitions) and then looping through it and printing the number of elements of each of the arrays. (This introduces communication so don't leave it in your production code.)
3. Many of the API calls on `RDD` have optional parameters for setting the number of partitions, and then there are calls like `repartition()` and `coalesce()` that can change the partitioning. Use them to fix problems you find using the above technique (but sometimes it will expose the need to rethink your algorithm.)
4. Check that you're actually using `RDD`s for all your large data, and haven't accidentally ended up with some big data structure on the master.

All of these assume that you have data skew problems rather than something more sinister. That's not guaranteed to be true, but you need to check your data skew situation before looking for something complicated. It's easy for data skew to creep in, especially given Spark's flexibility, and it can make a real mess.